# Disable/enable context menu for jQuery Dynatree not working

Tags: jquery, contextmenu, dynatree, jquery-dynatree

I am using the jQuery dynatree along with the context menu found [here](http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/09/jquery-context-menu-plugin/).  The issue I'm having is that I can't get the enable/disable of the context menu or individual items in the menu to work.  The plugin says I should be able to do this:

```
$("#contextMenu").enableContextMenu();
```

but that doesn't work for me.  Here's the menu:

```
 <!-- Definition of context menu -->
 <div id="contextMenu">
     <ul id="myMenu" class="contextMenu">
       <li class="resubmit"><a href="#resubmit">Resend</a></li>
     </ul>
 </div>
```

The menu shows and works fine if I don't put any enable/disable, but there are cases where the menu item is not available so I need to be able to control its state.  If I put in the enable/disable, the manu doesn't show at all.

Can anyone share how they got this to work?

UPDATE: I can only get the menu to show if I remove the DIV above.  Then it will show, but enable/disable using "myMenu" does nothing...

Comment: Try better investigate the Menu sample you have. And after you get the understanding how it works adjust this Menu in your project.

Comment: Sorry - I've been back over the only information including an example that doesn't use enable/disable and I can't find anything to try.  Have you done this before?  If so, can you provide code example? Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't disable the menu itself, so I had to handle it after the item is selected:

```
switch( action ) 
{
    case "resubmit":
        //-- show verify dialog
      var selectedNode = $("#tree").dynatree("getActiveNode");
      if(selectedNode == null) 
           break;
      var parentTitle = selectedNode.parent.data.title;
      if( parentTitle == "Error" || parentTitle == "To Lab" || parentTitle == "From Lab" )
            $('#dialog-confirm').dialog('open');
             break;
    default:
             alert("Invalid action '" + action + "' to node " + node);
}
```

I just check that the proper type node is selected to be able to take the action (look at parent, which is the containing folder).

Answer (score 0):

Came across the same issue, you can actually disable the context menu trigger like:

```
$(".dynatree-title").contextMenu(false)
```

And re-enable it with True. dynatree-title being the element the trigger is bound to.

Hope this helps anyone else who stumbles across this.

[Context menu documentation](http://medialize.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/docs.html#disable-trigger)